# What's going on with this class constructor function in the PHP MailChimp API wrapper?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm going to start using the [MailChimp API wrapper for PHP](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php) and I've come across something I don't understand.

The code is set up with a root file called `Mailchimp.php` which requires other .php files with classes for specific API calls (e.g. Templates, Campaigns, Lists, etc).

The parent class is called `Mailchimp`. Inside this class, the sub-files are instantiated by lines such as this:

```
$this->campaigns = new Mailchimp_Campaigns($this);
```

Inside the Campaigns.php file we have the class `Mailchimp_Campaigns`. The constructor for this class (which does **not** extend the parent) is called like this:

```
<?php

class Mailchimp_Campaigns {
    public function __construct(Mailchimp $master) {
        $this->master = $master;
    }
...
```

My question is: what's going on with the `(Mailchimp $master)` part? I understand that `$master` is really `$this` from the main class, but what's the `Mailchimp` part? Is that similar to a namespace, or is it simply to identify that it's an object of the `Mailchimp` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mailchimp part is the kind of object expected to be passed to the constructor.

This is called type hinting. See this link for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Type Hinting, awesome. That's exactly what I didn't know the term for and was left unable to search for more info. Appreciate it!